# Unable to download image with streamlit_echarts toolbox

Tags: python, streamlit, save-image, apache-echarts

I'm using streamlit_echarts in Python and the toolbox "saveAsImage" feature doesn't work. When I click on it, the toolbox disappears and nothing happens.

This behavior can be reproduced by running the following code:

```
from streamlit_echarts import st_echarts

my_options = {
  "toolbox": {"feature": {"saveAsImage" : {}}},
  "xAxis": {
    "type": 'category',
    "data": ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "type": 'value'
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      "type": 'line'
    }
  ]
}
st_echarts(options=my_options)
```

This code is inspired by the one available at the following address :
[text](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple)

Backup functionality works well if tested in JavaScript but does not work in Python. In JavaScript, the image is correctly loaded. In Python, the image is not loaded and the toolbox disappears.